# Why does Entity Framework use proxies for lazy loading?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lazy-loading

I am a little confused and I am wondering about why EF uses proxies to achieve lazy loading?

I mean why creating class on the fly instead of having something like this

```
public partial class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string PName { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Cat_Id { get; set; }
    private category;
    public Category Category { get{this.category = getCat(this.Id); return this.category;} set{this.category= value;} }
}

getCat(int Id)
{
  if(Id != 0)
  {   
      //Write Code 
  }
}
```

Comment: If it used your base entity classes, how would it know when to lazily load anything?

Comment: Moreover, you not always need lazy loading and you need to load all references at once.

Comment: Yeah, `//Write code`, you stop at the crucial point. Just try to write the required code there and you'll soon know why.

Comment: @GertArnold the question is not that he wants to write a code to do lazy loading, his question is why the people who developed lazy loading did not use some way like that instead of using proxies,

Comment: @Moh Yes, and my point is, if you try to write the required code there, you'll discover why. For one, you need a reference to context that created the entity. It must be possible to disable lazy loading context-wide. You'll clutter your entities with a pile of code that's always visible.

Comment: @DavidG could you explain what do you mean?

Comment: @GertArnold I got what your point, thanx.